# Cross-browser jQuery scrollbar operates with body tag

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I want to override browser's native scrollbars.
There are a lot of jQuery scrollbar plugins and I tried the majority of them such as `jScrollPane`, `PerfectScrollbar`, `TinyScrollbar` etc. I tried to apply them on body tag like below:

```
    $('html').css({"overflow":"hidden"}); //hide native scrollbars
    $('body').perfectScrollbar({wheelSpeed:10});
    //or
    //$('#scrollbar').perfectScrollbar({wheelSpeed:10});
```

It works improper way! So, I have a content div which is generated dynamically and its height is bigger than size of window, but there is no scrolls. Seems to me it works only with some div which has fixed size. It doesn't work even if I wrap some dynamic content in `div`:

```
<body>
<div id='scrollbar'>
<div id=dynamicContent'>It is filled by jQuery ajax</div>
</div>
</body>
```

So my question is how to modify any jQuery scrollbar plugin to work with dynamic content? I'd prefer to use `TinyScrollbar` because of its small size or `PerfectScrollbar`.

Comment: I do face the same problem with perfect scrollbar, So it will helpful if you could share the solution to use perfect scrollbar!

Comment: I posted my solution for `PerfectScrollbar`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, I have got another plugin and got that issue fixed :)

Comment: You should share your solution here for others.

Comment: I have given my solution here. Hope it will be useful!

Comment: From all the scrollbar plugins [NiceScroll 3](http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/) was the easiest and fastest to implement and truly works cross-browser, desktop and mobile, as well as on the `html` or `body` tag or any `div` you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of TinyScrollbar you have to call update() function on scrollable element henever contents of element changes.

```
var scrollbar = $("body");
$(scrollbar).update();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it's too late. I upgraded `PerfectScrollbar` instead. Now it works as I want.

Comment: Yeah, came across this question from some other question and never cared enough to look for date till I posted answer :)

Anyways its better to have answer in place than an unanswered question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough free time to test your solution. I just hope that it works correctly. So, I apply your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem too with `PerfectScrollbar`, but instead of using the customized plugin (in my case it didn't work) I would prefer create a div that covers the entire page and apply the plugin to the div. Besides, according to [this](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/issues/72) it's not a good practice to append a custom plugin to body.

First, add style to the body.

```
body
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And wrap an entire page with a div just after the body.

```
$("body").wrapInner( "<div class='bodyScroll' style='overflow:auto;height:100%;position:relative'></div>");
$(".bodyScroll").perfectScrollbar();
```

Comment: Glad to see another solution. Unfortunately, I faced with another problem connected with `PerfectScrollBar`. It works incorrectly with touch screens. If you can solve this issue, please let me know.

Comment: I think this one is a better solution than the one's available.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin called Nicescroll with lot of configuration parameters!
Check this out [niceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/index.html). I am using it with jQuery version 1.11.0 and it works perfect.

- It is able to style the main document scroll bar too.! and works for
  textareas and iframes, divs etc.
- It works for IE6+, Chrome 2+, Firefox 3+, Opera 9.5+ and Safari 4+.
- Also it supports other mobile devices.

Here is a sample code to use it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nice = $("html").niceScroll();
});
```

Comment: From all the scrollbar plugins this was easiest and fastest to implement and truly works cross-browser as well as on the `html` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted `PerfectScrollbar` for using with body tag. The source code you can get [here](http://pastebin.com/XqeR5H47). 
How it works in real life you can see on the website [Nolesh.com](http://www.nolesh.com). How to use it:

```
$('html').css({"overflow":"hidden"}); //hide native scrollbars
$('html, body').perfectScrollbar({wheelSpeed:50}); //apply PerfectScrollbar to body tag
//$('body').perfectScrollbar('update'); //to update
```

I hope it will save the time of someone else.